# Using preg_replace to remove space inside tags

Tags: php, preg-replace

Does anyone know how to use preg_replace in a way to change the following string

```
<a href="http://www.ulr .  php" target="   _blank"> http://www.url/thank  . php </ a>
```

into this

```
<a href="http://www.ulr.php" target="_blank">http://www.url/thank.php</a> more text
```

Thanks

Comment: Beware, that it can change the meaning of your markup. F.ex.: `class="link outer"` will be `class="linkouter"`. The preferred way is to produce the desired markup and/or validate it with something, like tidy http://php.net/tidy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$str='<a href="http://www.ulr .  php" target="   _blank"> http://www.url/thank  . php </ a>';
$res=preg_replace('/\s+\.\s+/','.',$str);
echo $res;
```